# Spring Data Neo4j 5 and dynamic @Properties - InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, spring-data-neo4j-5

This is my SDN 5 relationship entity:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS_VALUE_ON")
public class RelationshipValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private Decision decision;

    @EndNode
    private Valuable valuable;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private Object value;

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Everything is working fine, but when I try to change the logic onto new dynamic `@Properties` :

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS_VALUE_ON")
public class RelationshipValue {

    public static final String VALUE_PROPERTY_NAME = "value";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private Decision decision;

    @EndNode
    private Valuable valuable;

    @Properties(allowCast = true)
    private Map<String, Object> valueProperties = new HashMap<>();

    public Object getValue() {
        return valueProperties.get(VALUE_PROPERTY_NAME);
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        valueProperties.put(VALUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value);
    }

}
```

my tests fails with the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not map key=valueProperties.value, value=[Ljava.lang.Object;@52bef30b (type = class [Ljava.lang.Object;) because it is not a supported type.; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Could not map key=valueProperties.value, value=[Ljava.lang.Object;@52bef30b (type = class [Ljava.lang.Object;) because it is not a supported type.
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SessionFactoryUtils.convertOgmAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SessionBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.translateExceptionIfPossible(SessionBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.domain.dao.decision.characteristic.value.RelationshipValueDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(RelationshipValueDaoImpl.java:47)
    at com.example.domain.dao.decision.characteristic.value.RelationshipValueDaoImpl.synchronizeWithValues(RelationshipValueDaoImpl.java:107)
    at com.example.domain.dao.decision.characteristic.value.RelationshipValueDaoImpl.create(RelationshipValueDaoImpl.java:42)
    at com.example.domain.dao.decision.characteristic.value.RelationshipValueDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5a98b507.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.example.domain.dao.decision.characteristic.value.RelationshipValueDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a2f79bd4.create(<generated>)
    at com.example.domain.dao.decision.characteristic.value.ValueDaoImpl.create(ValueDaoImpl.java:86)
    at com.example.domain.dao.decision.characteristic.value.ValueDaoImpl.create(ValueDaoImpl.java:51)
    at com.example.domain.dao.decision.characteristic.value.ValueDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$db4e63af.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.example.domain.dao.decision.characteristic.value.ValueDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$532710cc.create(<generated>)
    at com.example.domain.DecisionCharacteristicIT.testDuplicateCharacteristicValues(DecisionCharacteristicIT.java:573)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Could not map key=valueProperties.value, value=[Ljava.lang.Object;@52bef30b (type = class [Ljava.lang.Object;) because it is not a supported type.
    at org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.MapCompositeConverter.addMapToProperties(MapCompositeConverter.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.MapCompositeConverter.toGraphProperties(MapCompositeConverter.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.MapCompositeConverter.toGraphProperties(MapCompositeConverter.java:37)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.FieldInfo.readComposite(FieldInfo.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.updateRelationshipEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:623)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.map(EntityGraphMapper.java:116)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:456)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.save(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SimpleNeo4jRepository.save(SimpleNeo4jRepository.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:573)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:554)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 67 more
```

Is there any way to emulate the same correct behaviour(as in the first code snippet) with the dynamic `@Properties` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because arrays are not supported as Map values.

Switching from array to List as an argument to the `setValue` method should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! It is working now with List. Why are arrays not supported as Map value there?

Comment: It's just not implemented ;)